# Reading through zipped lucene indices with solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I have lucene indices written by my application. Its a log archive. So after a time period, I just zip the indices and store it.

Now the question is, should I unzip the indices to search around it or is there any way in solr so that I can just read through the zipped indices. Made a couple of google searches, but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't an out of the box way to read through a zipped index with Solr. It would kill performance I guess. Unzip the archive manually, that's the way to go.

Comment: I was just looking around apache tika. But doesn't seem to be a fit in my case.

Comment: @greenhorn Right, Tika doesn't fit. It's useful to index binary data in Lucene/Solr.